# jquery : regex to detect + and - only

Tags: regex

i have a code to allow input only numbers and letter:

```
        if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
        }
```

how do i change the filter to allow the symbol : + and -
and remove numbers, letters and others? It must be has something to do with regex, which i not sure on how to do it. Any quick solution? thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove all characters except for + and -?

Comment: You don't need an if condition there. Replacement will not be done anyway unless there's at least 1 match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add those characters to the character set, and remove the ones you now want to clear out. However, in here, the `-` symbol has a special meaning and must be escaped like this:

```
    if (this.value.match(/[^+\-]/g)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^+\-]/g, '');
    }
```

As inhan points out in his comment, since the hyphen is the last character in the group, and therefore unambiguous, it may well be possibly to omit the escaping to have just this regex:

```
/[^+-]/g
```

But neither of us is totally sure if this will always work, whereas the escaped form certainly will.

Comment: Not when it's at the end of a character group, though ;)

Comment: Does that not depend on the parser? It's still strictly a special character in that context. Not sure on the answer, BTW, asking if you know?

Comment: No, AFAIK. But correct me, if somebody reading this knows otherwise.